# How to get Volumetrics with the Lightning Boy Shader

Tags: lighting, shader-nodes

The Lightning Boy shader means that you can get specific controlled colours through its use of colour ramps and RGB spliters, but since all the lights before going through the shader have to be either Red Green or Blue, it means if you want to do volumetrics, you'll always only get Bright saturated Red Green or Blue haze around the lights, instead of the intended colour.

Answer (score 1):

A way to fix this is by Faking the Haze around the Light using Spherical Gradients, Use a Spherical Gradient node and plug the mask into the Fac of a colour ramp node, Black with represent no haze, and anything else will represent the colour of the haze that will form around the sphereical gradient. then plug this into the Volume of the Material Output.

place the empty the spherical gradient is tracking in the same positon as the light (press tab on the spherical gradient node to know what the empty name is or assign a different empty) and change the colour on the colour ramp to the colour of haze you'd like around the light and your done.

if you want multiple haze colours or haze locations, simply duplicate the node setup, assign a new name so not to change the previous gradient, and assign a new empty, then plug it into a basic mix shader node with the previous node and there you go, multiple custom colours and haze with a lighting boy shader.

[image]